# How to use grouping key in GroupBy in RxJS,

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, grouping, angular9

I have structure returned by API

This is signature

```
methodApi(): Observable(Array<MyClass>)
```

This is data

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Red', parentId: null }
{ id: 2, name: 'Apple', parentId: 1 }
others
```

I want to group it by parentId

```
methodApi()
.pipe(groupby((x: MyClass[] => ...))) // THERE
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

MethodApi return **Observable<Array>**, in 'groupby' method as input parameter I have array, so I cannot refer to **parentId** property. When I change input param to **MyClass** then I get a compilation error.

How to resolve this grouping?
I use Angular 9.0 with RxJS 6.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create another observable stream from your array by using `from`, and then use the `groupBy` and after that convert it back to a result array:

```
methodApi().pipe(
  concatMap((result) => from(result)),
  groupBy((item) => item.parentId),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[example stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-l4gbzt?devtoolsheight=60)

You can also use `mergeAll`:

```
methodApi().pipe(
  mergeAll(),
  groupBy((item) => item.parentId),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[example stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-prhgl4?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple using `groupBy` operator as below,

```
methodApi().pipe(
  groupBy((item) => item.parentId),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
).subscribe(console.log) // should get you an array with groupBy parentId
```

Comment: This is how the group by operator is designed to be used, but OP's function is emitting a single array of objects. It is not a stream that emits multiple objects that can be grouped. OP needs a function that groups arrays, not observables.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the RxJs group by operator works. The RxJs operator groups objects that get emitted by the stream, you are looking to group items in an array that is emitted by the stream. You need a group by function that works on arrays, not observables. You could use a simple reduce that groups them all to an object with the parentId as the key.

```
methodApi()
.pipe(map(results => results.reduce(
  (group, item) => {
    if (group[item.parentId]) {
      group[item.parentId].push(item);
    } else {
      group[item.parentId] = [item];
    }
    return group;
  }, {})
)).subscribe(group => {});
```